# Does app pool have write permission on entire web directory by default in Azure Websites?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I'm working against a brand new Azure website and I'm very confused about the default ACLs. It seems that the app pool has write access by default. I made a simple page to test this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1>Testing Write Permissions</h1>
<p>In a typical IIS setup this throws <em>System.UnauthorizedAccessException</em>,
but it works in my new Azure Website. Does it work for you?</p>
<%
try {
    string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("test.html");
    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path, true);
    file.WriteLine("\n<p>" + System.DateTime.UtcNow + "</p>");
    file.Close();
    Response.Write("<p>I just wrote to <a href=\"test.html\">test.html</a>!</p>");
} catch (System.Exception ex) {
    Response.Write("<p>" + ex.ToString() + "</p>");
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

On my IIS that throws an error as expected, but when I use FTP to push that as `caniwrite.aspx` to my squeaky clean, new Azure Website it runs and test.html shows the edit. Do others see this behavior? Is this a widespread bug? Have I overlooked a configuration setting? Can you explain this behavior?

(I assume it is still a best practice to lock your app pool's access down so it can read most of the site but only write in a few places like app_data.)

Comment: My first test was on an S1 in US West. Same result on another new S1 instance in South Central US. `var user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User; var userName = user.Translate(typeof (System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));` reports `IIS APPPOOL\my-site-name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're showing is very different from giving anonymous users write access to your site.  Your site runs under it's own IIS context and that can do whatever it wants.  If anonymous users have access to a given URL (which they do here) then whatever code that URL triggers will be executed.

What it looks like you're looking for here is to prevent anonymous users from accessing specific urls on your site.  For that you'll want to look up how to add Authentication and Authorization to your site

Comment: I was a little sloppy with my language there, I updated the question to reflect that I am asking about the APP Pool. In standard IIS, "whatever it wants" is still restricted by the default permissions given to the app pool--which does not include writing outside of app_data. Why is that a default in Azure? Or is it? Did you get the same result in one of your Azure instances? I have a good handle on authentication and authorization and url rewriting--not worried about those here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I expected to jump through a hurdle like `ICACLS test.html /grant "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool":F` or msdeploy `<setAcl path="Default Web Site\test.html" setAclAccess="Write" setAclResourceType="File"` in order to make this work instead of it working out of the box. Maybe this is just Platform as a Service making my life easier and APPPOOL is plenty secure even with the extra write access. I couldn't find any recent IIS hardening guidelines to clarify. Umbraco has lots of setacls for giving directories write access so I'm not the only one holding on to that idea.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  No, there isn't any such restriction on azure websites as you saw.  Your site's app pool identity has write access to the entire folder.  The access limits were probably useful on a server which you share with other sites and tentants in order to make sure no one stomps over someone else's files. The Azure Websites sandbox takes care of that issue so the wwwroot folder no longer needs that extra padlock